# Packery Grid Layout - Problems with border/padding and overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, grid

I have been working on a grid layout using metafizzy isotope packery mode and have set up a codepen below to show you my issue.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgKdpL

I am almost happy with my grid except for two issues.

1 - I applied padding to the main grid selector class "griditem" which i would expect to apply a simply white edge around all grid items. However the results were mixed and some gaps are smaller/bigger than others. I have tried to produce the same thing with using CSS borders but had the same issue.

```
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
   margin: 0!important;
   padding: 10px!important;
}
```

2 - There is then a overlay on each grid item that reveals a title/heading, but due to the padding the overlay runs off is there a way to stop this happening?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgKdpL

Appreciate any help.

UPDATE

Have applied the answers from below to the codepen, rollover state now fixed and fine. As you can see though uneven border/padding remains e.g. on first blue box.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

At the top of your CSS code, int the `*` selector block, add this:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0
```

The issue with space is almost always a problem with the browser adding extra margins and such, a simple CSS reset like this should take care of it. For more detail see [Eric Meyer's CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it improved slightly but i am still seeing a unequal border. It seems to be mainly on the square-ish third sized box. I will check out the CSS reset sheet too, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the margin that is on your body/html tag:

   ```
   html, body {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }
   ```
2. `#wrapper .text-overlay` uses 100% width and height in it. Since you are using absolute positioning, you could use the top, bottom, left, right properties instead. Try this:

   ```
   #wrapper .text-overlay {
       position: absolute;
       visibility: hidden;
       background-color: RGBA(40, 44, 52, 0.9);
       font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
       letter-spacing: 0.5px;
       display: block;
       margin: 0 auto;
       top: 10px;
       left: 10px;
       right: 10px;
       bottom: 10px;
       color: #fff;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, the first point helped to take some unwanted pixels out from around the grid, however i am still seeing the uneven border. As for your second point, using top, bottom, left and right that worked perfectly and has fixed the overlap on the rollover state, Thank you.